# Using SignalR to read a message from a topic in service bus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Is there a way i can point a signalr mvc app to point to an existing topic in service bus. ?
So lets say in case of the standard chat application, can we modify it to read an existing topic then creating one.

Comment: did you find any way to achieve this?